# Draw the lattice under a group isomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Let $M$ and $N$ be normal subgroups of $G$ s.t. $G=MN$. Prove that $G/(M\cap N)\cong (G/M)\times (G/N)$.

I have got the proof. But the question asks to draw the lattice. Is there any lattice? Since we don't know what's the groups $M$, $N$ and $G$ are like.

What's the lattice?

Answer (score 1):

I think one means the 4-element lattice $\{M,N,\inf(M,N)=M\cap N, \sup(M,N)=MN=G\}$.

Comment: @ Babak S.: Dear  Babak S., sorry, I don't English well so I don't understand your comment.